# Can I get attributes using XPath itself in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a little problem that when I try to get some attribute like `href`, `id` or `text`, I'm not able to do that using `XPath` itself in `Selenium` - `Python`.

I have to do this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPath).get_attribute(attr)` instead of this: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPath/@attr)`

I suppose that this is because method `find_element_by_xpath` checks, whether the output is a real `WebElement`.

Is there some way to avoid long `get_attribute(attr)` by using `XPath` syntax?

Comment: `find_element_by_...()` method search requested element on page and return it if present, but not its attributes or attributes values..

Comment: I would imagine not, as `driver.find_element` returns WebElement. How ever maybe Python as some work around for this.